# Code refactoring: Outsourcing substeps to helper classes

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, refactoring, code-cleanup

When a class performs a complicated and lengthy task, I usually refactor it step-by-step based on the situation, as shown below.

**Version 0**

```
public class ComplicatedTaskDoer{

    public void doComplicatedTask(){
      // lots of complicated code
    }

}
```

**Version 1:**

Break it down into multiple smaller sub-tasks

```
public class ComplicatedTaskDoer{

    public void doComplicatedTask(){
      init();
      doSubStepA();
      doB();
      doC();
      wrapUp();
    }
}
```

**Version 2:**

If complicated enough, outsource sub-tasks to *helper classes*. I don't really code to *interfaces* in this case.

```
public class ComplicatedTaskDoer{

    public void doComplicatedTask(){
      init();
      subsetpADoerClass.doA();
      classB.doB();
      classC.doC();
      wrapUp();
    }
}
```

**Version 3:**

If I see my self in need of adding more components in the future and if there's a valid pattern in terms of input and output objects, I do the following.

```
public class ComplicatedTaskController{
    //injected
    List<SomethingHelperComponent> components;
    public void doComplicatedTask(){
      init();
      for(SomethingHelperComponent component : components){
           component.process(commonInput);
      }
      wrapUp();
    }   
}
```

I'm more curious about the version 3. I ended up doing that quite a few times.

**Q1)**
Is there any existing pattern that's similar and probably more effective? It's not 'chain of responsibilities' that I'm looking for as I prefer those components to be independent (*open to discuss*). It looks more like a configurable variation of template method pattern.

**Q2)** 
I've always named the main class as 'SomethingController' and the helper classes with 'SomethingHelper' or 'SomethingComponent'. I recently realized that 'controller' was misleading and 'helper' was non-informative.

It'd be really helpful to get some ideas on correctly naming those classes. How'd you name them?

**Q3)** 
Did you think that the refactoring was reasonable?

**Q4)**
Subjective: Is it OK to keep some steps in the helper methods and outsource some steps to helper classes? I usually restrain myself from unit-testing non-public methods.

**Q5)**
Do you consider helper classes, i.e. with no code-to-interfaces, to be a code smell? May be I can even declare them as inner classes?

Comment: First thing that I usually do is [replacing method with method object](http://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceMethodWithMethodObject.html). Refactoring in such a class then is easier.

Comment: Actually, I think this is a quite unrealistic pattern. When you refactor legacy code, the problem is to keep the context between the parts and define a clean set of parameters among them.

Comment: i would classify this question as very broad which would get multiple suggestions. what i would suggest is design something reasonable based on the problem at hand rather than looking for multiple solutions. sometimes a solution looking too simple might be the right approach and yes i support Helper classes.

Comment: @Leo usually the version 3 is not really preceded by version 2 and refactoring. I do version 3 if I'm implementing from scratch and I see a pattern. For example, I've a search query and I wanna run a bunch of algorithms to expand/enrich it, etc. The main class will be the face of the API whereas the substeps are individual algorithms and I see myself adding more algorithms in the future to enhance it further.

Comment: @phani to be honest, I think #1 is easier to read and maintain if the idea is to break a complex processing into smaller parts. #3 reminds me the Command Pattern, which is useful in some cases (when you can compose operations), but usually it's not the case.

Comment: And I agree the question is too broad

Answer (score 0):

### Configuration of classes

This is legit solution. It is sometimes seen with spring where partial tasks 
implement some interface and through spring magic you can have list of all implementations with

```
@Autowired
List<MyInterface> myParts;
```

### Design Pattern Name

As for naming I think you could think about it as as special case of chain of responsibility. It might not be really accurate, but shows your intention pretty well.

### Naming of classes

I'd go for suffix `.*Algorithm`

Name main Interface like `DoSomethingComplicatedAlgorithm` or `DoSomethingComplicatedAlgorithmStep`. Classes which implement interface would be called `WhatPartOfAlgorithmIsUsedHere`

### Helper Classes

If they they'll let you avoid code duplication and you have no better domain model than you can use them. On the other hand leave it as a last resort option. Might be small code smell, but certainly your application won't burn.